# .htaccess rewrite of 2 variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on some legacy code and running into a trouble in .htaccess that I cannot overcome.

Currently, if you enter in a browser:

```
/news/name-of-news-article.php
```

the .htaccess file will call the database:

```
RewriteRule /news/(.*).php /pages/news.php?url=$1 [L]
```

and work just fine.

Trouble is, that I would like to include an optional variable in the url so that if I want to include an autoplay video - everything I try in the .htaccess to look for it, seems to kill the page and if I don't change the .htaccess it can't find the optional video=true.

```
/news/name-of-news-article.php?video=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `QSA` parameter to your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule /news/(.*).php /pages/news.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @haotion Liu - You are a lifesaver. Honestly I spent far too much time trying to be fancy. Really appreciate the help. Will mark as answered as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: @Brandrally :) My pleasure